# Regular Expression for set of double number with semi-colon delimeted

Tags: regex

Today I attemped several time to build regular expression to validate a set of double number with semi-colon delimeted following example data below:

**Should match:**

123.1234567890
123.1234567890;123.1234567890;123.1234567890

**Should not match:**

123.1234567890;
123.1234567890;123.1234567890;123.1234567890;

If you have any idea, Could you please help me ?

Thank you very much

Comment: which language? and what was the regex you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
(\d+\.\d+;)*\d+\.\d+(?![\d;])
```

to match the whole `123.1234567890;123.1234567890;123.1234567890`

```
\d+\.\d+(?![\d;])
```

to match just the last.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's work well in online IDE, Do you know is it compatible in Pattern in XML Schema ?

Comment: XML Schema [does not support](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html) lookaround, so you can use `[^\d;]` instead of `(?![\d;])`. It should work even with the linebreaks, but it won't work if the last digit is at the real end of the string.